# Oracle Threads and Processes

Tags: oracle

Here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/A95907_01/diff_uni.htm#1077398
I found that on Windows Oracle is thread based, while on Unix this is process based. Why it is like that?

What's more, there are many Oracle processes http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/concepts/processes/index.html regardless the system.

Why log writer and db writer are implemented as processes... and the query execution is done using threads (windows) or processes (unix).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle makes use of a SGA shared memory area to store information that is (and has to be) accessible to all sessions/transactions. For example, when a row is locked, that lock is in memory (as an attribute of the row) and all the other transactions need to see it is locked.

In windows a thread cannot access another process's memory

> [threads cannot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366525%28VS.85%29.aspx) access memory that
>   belongs to another process, which
>   protects a process from being
>   corrupted by another process.

As such, in Windows Oracle must be a single process with multiple threads.
On OS's supporting the sharing of memory between processes then it is less work for Oracle to work as a multi-process architecture and leave the process management to the OS.

Oracle runs a number of background threads/processes to do work that is (or can be) asynchronous to the other processes. That way those can continue even when other processes/threads are blocked or busy.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer I posted earlier on in similar vein to this question '[What is process and thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319924/what-is-process-and-thread/2320078#2320078)'. Windows makes extensive use of threads in this fashion. Unlike *nix/Linux based systems which are based on threads. And see here also, this link is a direct link(which is embedded in the first link I have given) to the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293581/does-linux-time-division-processes-or-threads/2293724#2293724) I gave on how Linux time divisions threads and processes.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: And that's why Oracle also has many processes per instance? I'll change the question for that

Comment: Yes.  In Oracle on Windows, all the processes in Oracle on *nix(pmon, smon, lgwr, et.al.) are threads inside ORACLE.EXE.